# A square loop of side length $a$ with current $I$ running through it. What is the magnetic field at a distance $x$ from the center of the square?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

We have a square loop of side length a with current I running through it. What is the magnetic field, B at a distance x from the center of the square?

[image]

So far, I know that I have to use the magnetic field formula (shown in the picture). I also determined that the magnetic field points out of the center of the square (by right-hand rule).

I'm not sure how to proceed. So far, I know that I have to eventually integrate but I do not know how to set up the integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using principle of superposition.
Before solving this question,try to find field at a particular distance from a single finite wire of given length.You can solve it using biot-stavart law and integrating[for a single finite wire].Once done,use the result to compute field here.Find distance of point B from the middle of one side[Hint-Use pythagoras theorem].By symmetry,each side will contribute same field in magnitude .Finally,take the VECTOR sum of each of the four fields produced by four wires.
Overall if you know formula for field at perpendicular distance from middle of wire,this question then DOESN'T require integration at all.

Comment: Ok so from a problem before I found out that the magnetic field due to a single wire is B = (uI/4piD)[sin (theta1) + sin (theta 2)]. So now I just find out the value for D, theta1, and theta2 and then multiply by 4 because of symmetry?

Comment: @idk you dont just multiply them by 4.You have to take vector sum not scalar.